# Plotting odds ratio's and 95% confidence intervals

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create a plot in R, with odds ratio's of four different variables and their 95% confidence intervals. I want it to look kind of similar to the example image below: 
[image]

The figure above only includes the (b) picture, since the (a) picture is almost similar and I only wanted to show the lay out.

I have been searching on the web, but found nothing that looked similar like this. Hope you can give me some advice!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

More or less, with native R:

```
### artificial data ####
set.seed(321)
bs<-sort(runif(20,-2,2))
sd<-runif(20,1,2)
li1<-bs-2*sd
li2<-bs+2*sd
dat<-data.frame(li1,bs,li2)
pos<-c(1:5,7:11,13:17,19:23)
xl=range(dat)
plot(1,type="n",xlim=xl,ylim=c(1,25),ylab="",frame.plot = F,yaxt = "n",xlab="lr")
for (i in 1:length(dat[,1])){
  lines(dat[i,],rep(pos[i],3),lty=pos[i]%%6,pch="|",type = "b",cex = .5)
}
abline(v=0,lty=3)
points(dat[,2],pos,pch="*",cex=.8)
text(-2,pos[c(5,10,15,20)]+.95,paste("Text",1:4),cex=.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Robert. This is exactly what I meant!
Two questions: I am working with 3 different models (instead of the 5 that are used in the example picture and plot). When I use the code above, the order of the line types is incorrect. I am not exactly sure, how to fix this. Should I look into `lty`?

I also got an error message for the points code: namely `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`. I thought this had to do with the 2 in `points(dataf[,2],`.  FYI I use `pos <- c(1:3, 4:7)` to test the model with my own data.

Do you have suggestions for this?